# <link> vs <a>: when to use one over the other?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have some confusion between `<link>` and `<a>`.

I know that in order to add CSS to an HTML document we use the `<link>` tag, for example:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/spinner/styles.css?ln=css" />
```

But, I can't understand why we do not use an anchor `<a>` tag (as it contains the same necessary attributes), something like:

```
 <a type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/spinner/styles.css?ln=css" />
```

Are these two tags interchangeable? Also, if this is possible, then how do we choose one over the other and why?

**Update:**

I got that confusion, because I saw in *The Complete Reference HTML & CSS* book regarding the `rel` attribute of the `<a>` Tag, that:

> **rel**:  For anchors containing the `href` attribute, this attribute
>   specifies the relationship of the target object to the link object.

So I thought that it could do the same function as the `<link>` tag.

Comment: Is there a comparison?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh is it possible ?

Comment: Why would that be possible.. There are different functions they both do

Comment: @NaeemShaikh is it an unappropriate question ?

Comment: @Tarik It's a valid question, its just that most people find the answer to be trivial, or they don't think about it like you are.

Comment: @Jon.. Yes it is a valid question.. I didnt say its not valid

Comment: @Tarik.. I didnt say its invalid question.. But its quite like comparing a fish with a donkey..

Comment: @NaeemShaikh still a valid and interesting comparison from an evolutionary point of view...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Attributes are not the same as the tag they are in.

[`<link />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element), i.e. it can not have anything inside of it. All it does is specify a relationship with another document. Additionally, the `<link>` tag is only used in the `<head>` section.

[`<a></a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) on the other hand, is not an empty element and specifies an object to be created on the page - like a clickable link or image - which takes the user to some other location. This tag is only used in the `<body>` section.

So, even though the tags *can* have the same attributes, that does not mean they do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that also mean that  we can't use <a> to add styling ? as rel dosn't mean the same thing ? is that right ?

Comment: @Tarik: that is correct.  Literally open this page's source and you'll see the use cases.

Comment: That's correct. As Piotr Perak's answer says, using the `a` tag would just create a clickable link to the css file, not actually include it in the document.

Comment: Actually <link> is allowed in the body since 2016. See [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#allowed-in-the-body). So the answer needs to be updated.

Comment: @Spencer Yes, one of the usages of the <link> in the body is to add microdata to HTML document. For example, see the Example 3 on this page https://schema.org/Product which defines 'availability' for a product.

Answer (score 11):

You can't use A tag to add css to HTML document because it is meant for creating clickable hyperlinks between documents.

But if you would like to create link allowing users to download css file you could do this

```
<a type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/spinner/styles.css?ln=css">Download css</a>
```

Answer (score 10):

Anything in `<a>insideanchortag</a>` is visible to end user

But you cant see the `<link  />` data in end user view,
It is only visible in inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

KISS
very simple

LINK == inbound object

A == outbound object